# Stopped Logging : Logback SiftingAppender log folder change runtime using MDC in Multitenant spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j, multi-tenant, log4j

I have multi-tenant application followed by microservices created in spring boot version 1.4.3, i have generated tenant wise logs in different folders inside logs folder of tomcat.

A Problem which i am facing is after some time/hours/days/weeks my logs will stop but application work in backgroud. I am trying to find root cause of the same but failed.

In java code some classes using Slf4j and some classes using log4j to print logs.

As mentined i am using SiftingAppender and changing logFolder variable from Filter/Intercepter based on the tenant.

previously i was doing MDC.clear() to remove logFolder from MDC, then i have moved to MDC.remove("logFolder") but that also not worked

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}}" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <!-- This is MDC value -->
    <!-- We will assign a value to 'logFileName' via Java code -->
    <appender name="FILE-THREAD" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <!-- This is MDC value -->
        <!-- We will assign a value to 'logFileName' via Java code -->
        <discriminator>
            <key>logFolder</key>
            <defaultValue>main</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${logFileFolder}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>${LOG_FILE}/${logFolder}/enquiryengine.log</file>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
                </encoder>
                <!-- <file>${LOG_FILE}</file> -->
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}/${logFolder}/enquiryengine.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
                    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
                        <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
                    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                </rollingPolicy>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
    <springProfile name="development">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="production">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="staging">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="testing3">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="testing">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="testing2">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <jmxConfigurator />
</configuration>
```

public class MyClass extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    MDC.put(UtilConstant.LOG_FOLDER_NAME, "dynamicTenantFolderName");

    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    MDC.remove(UtilConstant.LOG_FOLDER_NAME);

}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    MDC.remove(UtilConstant.LOG_FOLDER_NAME);
}
```

}

public class TenantRequestFilter implements Filter {

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    MDC.remove(UtilConstant.LOG_FOLDER_NAME);
    MDC.put(UtilConstant.LOG_FOLDER_NAME, "dynamicLogFolderName");
    // Goes to default servlet
    chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    MDC.remove(UtilConstant.LOG_FOLDER_NAME);
}
```

}

As logs are not working so i will not get any stack trace, Expected Result is logs generation should not stop.

Answer (score 0):

The default `Timeout for Siftappender is 30 Minutes`,
If no logs are written in 30mins then the siftappender gets timeout and no further logs on that MDC will be processed.

To overcome this,

**1. You can increase the time limit as per the application's requirement**

**2. Have a scheduler to print log after particular interval, so that it never gets timeout**

Refer Document: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html